# Stored procedure finding products between a range of prices

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

So I would like the ability to filter a range of prices. So for my filters I have something like this, which just calculates 6 price ranges bases on the min price and max price products.

[image]

When the tick boxes are checked, the options are passed into the stored procedure.
I use this code, which checks how many tick boxes are ticked, and passes the parameters into the stored procedure.

```
string lowPrices = "";
                string highPrices = "";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceRange))
                {
                    if (priceRange.Contains(','))
                    {
                        var ranges = priceRange.Split(',');
                        foreach (var r in ranges)
                        {
                            var range = r.Split('-');
                            var low = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Parse(range[0]));
                            var high = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Parse(range[1]));
                            lowPrices += low.ToString() + ",";
                            highPrices += high.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                        lowPrices = lowPrices.TrimEnd(',').Trim();
                        highPrices = highPrices.TrimEnd(',').Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var range = priceRange.Split('-');
                        var lowPrice = Decimal.Parse(range[0]);
                        var highPrice = Decimal.Parse(range[1]);
                        minPriceConverted = lowPrice;
                        maxPriceConverted = highPrice;
                    }
                }
```

The minPriceConverted and maxPriceConverted were easy enough with a simple greater then or less than expression as they are decimals passed to the stored procedure. However trying to do a range of decimals is proving difficult.
I thought maybe converting them to ints and using in, but clearly that won't work so I don't know what I was thinking here:

```
IF @PriceRangeMin is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (CONVERT(INT, p.SpecialPrice) in (' + CAST(@PriceRangeMin AS nvarchar(max)) + '))
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (CONVERT(INT, p.Price) in (' + CAST(@PriceRangeMin AS nvarchar(max)) + '))
                )
            )'
    END
    --max price range
    IF @PriceRangeMax is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (CONVERT(INT, p.SpecialPrice) in (' + CAST(@PriceRangeMax AS nvarchar(max)) + '))
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (CONVERT(INT, p.Price) in (' + CAST(@PriceRangeMax AS nvarchar(max)) + '))
                )
            )'
    END
```

I think my only option is to declare 6 minprice and maxprice vars in the stored procedure(as there will never be more than 6) and check for nulls etc like so:

```
@PriceRangeMin1     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax1     decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceRangeMin2     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax2     decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceRangeMin3     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax3     decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceRangeMin4     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax4     decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceRangeMin5     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax5     decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceRangeMin6     decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceRangeMax6     decimal(18, 4) = null

--min price
    IF @PriceRangeMin1 is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.SpecialPrice >= ' + CAST(@PriceRangeMin1 AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.Price >= ' + CAST(@PriceRangeMin1 AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
            )'
    END

//so on u get the idea
```

Is there a more elegant way I can accomplish this task, I would like to know if there is a better way I can do this.
Thanks

Here is the full procedure too:

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged]    Script Date: 2/19/2020 10:13:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged]
(
    @CategoryIds        nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --a list of category IDs (comma-separated list). e.g. 1,2,3
    @ManufacturerId     int = 0,
    @ManufacturerIds    nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)
    @StoreId            int = 0,
    @VendorId           int = 0,
    @WarehouseId        int = 0,
    @ProductTypeId      int = null, --product type identifier, null - load all products
    @VisibleIndividuallyOnly bit = 0,   --0 - load all products , 1 - "visible indivially" only
    @MarkedAsNewOnly    bit = 0,    --0 - load all products , 1 - "marked as new" only
    @ProductTagId       int = 0,
    @FeaturedProducts   bit = null, --0 featured only , 1 not featured only, null - load all products
    @PriceMin           decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceMax           decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @Keywords           nvarchar(4000) = null,
    @SearchDescriptions bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product descriptions
    @SearchSku          bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product SKU
    @SearchProductTags  bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product tags
    @UseFullTextSearch  bit = 0,
    @FullTextMode       int = 0, --0 - using CONTAINS with <prefix_term>, 5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>, 10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>
    @FilteredSpecs      nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --filter by specification attribute options (comma-separated list of IDs). e.g. 14,15,16
    @LanguageId         int = 0,
    @OrderBy            int = 0, --0 - position, 5 - Name: A to Z, 6 - Name: Z to A, 10 - Price: Low to High, 11 - Price: High to Low, 15 - creation date
    @AllowedCustomerRoleIds nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --a list of customer role IDs (comma-separated list) for which a product should be shown (if a subjet to ACL)
    @PageIndex          int = 0, 
    @PageSize           int = 2147483644,
    @ShowHidden         bit = 0,
    @OverridePublished  bit = null, --null - process "Published" property according to "showHidden" parameter, true - load only "Published" products, false - load only "Unpublished" products
    @LoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds bit = 0, --a value indicating whether we should load the specification attribute option identifiers applied to loaded products (all pages)
    @ListItemOnAmazon   bit = null,
    /*@ListItemOnEbay       bit = null,*/
    @FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds nvarchar(MAX) = null OUTPUT, --the specification attribute option identifiers applied to loaded products (all pages). returned as a comma separated list of identifiers
    @TotalRecords       int = null OUTPUT,
    @SearchCode   int = 0
)
AS
BEGIN

    /* Products that filtered by keywords */
    CREATE TABLE #KeywordProducts
    (
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE
        @SearchKeywords bit,
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @sql_orderby nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --filter by keywords
    SET @Keywords = isnull(@Keywords, '')
    SET @Keywords = rtrim(ltrim(@Keywords))
    IF ISNULL(@Keywords, '') != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SearchKeywords = 1

        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
        BEGIN
            --remove wrong chars (' ")
            SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '''', '')
            SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '"', '')

            --full-text search
            IF @FullTextMode = 0 
            BEGIN
                --0 - using CONTAINS with <prefix_term>
                SET @Keywords = ' "' + @Keywords + '*" '
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                --5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>
                --10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>

                --clean multiple spaces
                WHILE CHARINDEX('  ', @Keywords) > 0 
                    SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '  ', ' ')

                DECLARE @concat_term nvarchar(100)              
                IF @FullTextMode = 5 --5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>
                BEGIN
                    SET @concat_term = 'OR'
                END 
                IF @FullTextMode = 10 --10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>
                BEGIN
                    SET @concat_term = 'AND'
                END

                --now let's build search string
                declare @fulltext_keywords nvarchar(4000)
                set @fulltext_keywords = N''
                declare @index int      

                set @index = CHARINDEX(' ', @Keywords, 0)

                -- if index = 0, then only one field was passed
                IF(@index = 0)
                    set @fulltext_keywords = ' "' + @Keywords + '*" '
                ELSE
                BEGIN       
                    DECLARE @first BIT
                    SET  @first = 1         
                    WHILE @index > 0
                    BEGIN
                        IF (@first = 0)
                            SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + ' ' + @concat_term + ' '
                        ELSE
                            SET @first = 0

                        SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + '"' + SUBSTRING(@Keywords, 1, @index - 1) + '*"'                  
                        SET @Keywords = SUBSTRING(@Keywords, @index + 1, LEN(@Keywords) - @index)                       
                        SET @index = CHARINDEX(' ', @Keywords, 0)
                    end

                    -- add the last field
                    IF LEN(@fulltext_keywords) > 0
                        SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + ' ' + @concat_term + ' ' + '"' + SUBSTRING(@Keywords, 1, LEN(@Keywords)) + '*"'   
                END
                SET @Keywords = @fulltext_keywords
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --usual search by PATINDEX
            SET @Keywords = '%' + @Keywords + '%'
        END
        --PRINT @Keywords

        --product name
        SET @sql = '
        INSERT INTO #KeywordProducts ([ProductId])
        SELECT p.Id
        FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE '
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[Name], @Keywords) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Name]) > 0 '


        --localized product name
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        UNION
        SELECT lp.EntityId
        FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
            AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
            AND lp.LocaleKey = N''Name'''
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '


        IF @SearchDescriptions = 1
        BEGIN
            --product short description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[ShortDescription], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[ShortDescription]) > 0 '


            --product full description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[FullDescription], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[FullDescription]) > 0 '



            --localized product short description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT lp.EntityId
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''ShortDescription'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '


            --localized product full description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT lp.EntityId
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''FullDescription'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '
        END

        --SKU
        IF @SearchSku = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[Sku], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Sku]) > 0 '
        END

        IF @SearchProductTags = 1
        BEGIN
            --product tag
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT pptm.Product_Id
            FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN ProductTag pt with(NOLOCK) ON pt.Id = pptm.ProductTag_Id
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(pt.[Name], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, pt.[Name]) > 0 '

            --localized product tag
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT pptm.Product_Id
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with(NOLOCK) ON lp.EntityId = pptm.ProductTag_Id
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''ProductTag''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''Name'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '
        END

        --PRINT (@sql)
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Keywords nvarchar(4000)', @Keywords

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SearchKeywords = 0
    END

    --filter by category IDs
    SET @CategoryIds = isnull(@CategoryIds, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredCategoryIds
    (
        CategoryId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredCategoryIds (CategoryId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@CategoryIds, ',') 
    DECLARE @CategoryIdsCount int   
    SET @CategoryIdsCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredCategoryIds)

    --filter by customer role IDs (access control list)
    SET @AllowedCustomerRoleIds = isnull(@AllowedCustomerRoleIds, '')   
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredCustomerRoleIds
    (
        CustomerRoleId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredCustomerRoleIds (CustomerRoleId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@AllowedCustomerRoleIds, ',')

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    DECLARE @PageUpperBound int
    DECLARE @RowsToReturn int
    SET @RowsToReturn = @PageSize * (@PageIndex + 1)    
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex
    SET @PageUpperBound = @PageLowerBound + @PageSize + 1

    CREATE TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp 
    (
        [Id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )

    SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO #DisplayOrderTmp ([ProductId])
    SELECT p.Id
    FROM
        Product p with (NOLOCK)'

    IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pcm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pcm.ProductId'
    END

    IF @ManufacturerId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Manufacturer_Mapping pmm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pmm.ProductId'
    END
    --filter by manufacturers(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)
    IF @ManufacturerIds != null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Manufacturer_Mapping pmm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pmm.ProductId'
    END

    IF ISNULL(@ProductTagId, 0) != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pptm.Product_Id'
    END

    --searching by keywords
    IF @SearchKeywords = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        JOIN #KeywordProducts kp
            ON  p.Id = kp.ProductId'
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + '
    WHERE
        p.Deleted = 0'

    --filter by category
    IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pcm.CategoryId IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM #FilteredCategoryIds)'

        IF @FeaturedProducts IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pcm.IsFeaturedProduct = ' + CAST(@FeaturedProducts AS nvarchar(max))
        END
    END

    --filter by manufacturer
    IF @ManufacturerId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId = ' + CAST(@ManufacturerId AS nvarchar(max))

        IF @FeaturedProducts IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.IsFeaturedProduct = ' + CAST(@FeaturedProducts AS nvarchar(max))
        END
    END
    --filter by manufacturers(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)

    --select * from STRING_SPLIT(@ManufacturerIds, ',') INTO #ManufacturerIds
    IF @ManufacturerIds != null
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #ManufacturerIds
        (
            ManufacturerId int not null
        )
        INSERT INTO #ManufacturerIds
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ManufacturerIds, ',')
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId in (5,29)'--check last tab, so (use temp table)
        DROP TABLE #ManufacturerIds
    END

    --filter by vendor
    IF @VendorId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.VendorId = ' + CAST(@VendorId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --filter by warehouse
    IF @WarehouseId > 0
    BEGIN
        --we should also ensure that 'ManageInventoryMethodId' is set to 'ManageStock' (1)
        --but we skip it in order to prevent hard-coded values (e.g. 1) and for better performance
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND  
            (
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND
                    p.WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                OR
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses > 0 AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
                    WHERE [pwi].WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ' AND [pwi].ProductId = p.Id))
            )'
    END

    --filter by product type
    IF @ProductTypeId is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ProductTypeId = ' + CAST(@ProductTypeId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --filter by "visible individually"
    IF @VisibleIndividuallyOnly = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.VisibleIndividually = 1'
    END

    --filter by "marked as new"
    IF @MarkedAsNewOnly = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.MarkAsNew = 1
        AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN ISNULL(p.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') and ISNULL(p.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999''))'
    END

    --filter by product tag
    IF ISNULL(@ProductTagId, 0) != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pptm.ProductTag_Id = ' + CAST(@ProductTagId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --"Published" property
    IF (@OverridePublished is null)
    BEGIN
        --process according to "showHidden"
        IF @ShowHidden = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            AND p.Published = 1'
        END
    END
    ELSE IF (@OverridePublished = 1)
    BEGIN
        --published only
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Published = 1'
    END
    ELSE IF (@OverridePublished = 0)
    BEGIN
        --unpublished only
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Published = 0'
    END

    --show hidden
    IF @ShowHidden = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Deleted = 0
        AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN ISNULL(p.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') and ISNULL(p.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999''))'
    END

    --min price
    IF @PriceMin is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.SpecialPrice >= ' + CAST(@PriceMin AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.Price >= ' + CAST(@PriceMin AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
            )'
    END

    --max price
    IF @PriceMax is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.SpecialPrice <= ' + CAST(@PriceMax AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.Price <= ' + CAST(@PriceMax AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
            )'
    END

    --show hidden and ACL
    IF @ShowHidden = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (p.SubjectToAcl = 0 OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM #FilteredCustomerRoleIds [fcr]
            WHERE
                [fcr].CustomerRoleId IN (
                    SELECT [acl].CustomerRoleId
                    FROM [AclRecord] acl with (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE [acl].EntityId = p.Id AND [acl].EntityName = ''Product''
                )
            ))'
    END

    --show hidden and filter by store
    IF @StoreId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (p.LimitedToStores = 0 OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM [StoreMapping] sm with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE [sm].EntityId = p.Id AND [sm].EntityName = ''Product'' and [sm].StoreId=' + CAST(@StoreId AS nvarchar(max)) + '
            ))'
    END

    --filter by specification attribution options
    SET @FilteredSpecs = isnull(@FilteredSpecs, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredSpecs
    (
        SpecificationAttributeOptionId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredSpecs (SpecificationAttributeOptionId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@FilteredSpecs, ',')
    DECLARE @SpecAttributesCount int    
    SET @SpecAttributesCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredSpecs)
    IF @SpecAttributesCount > 0
    BEGIN
        --do it for each specified specification option
        DECLARE @SpecificationAttributeOptionId int
        DECLARE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [SpecificationAttributeOptionId]
        FROM [#FilteredSpecs]
        OPEN cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SpecificationAttributeOption INTO @SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            AND p.Id in (select psam.ProductId from [Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping] psam with (NOLOCK) where psam.AllowFiltering = 1 and psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = ' + CAST(@SpecificationAttributeOptionId AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
            --fetch next identifier
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SpecificationAttributeOption INTO @SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        END
        CLOSE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
        DEALLOCATE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
    END

    IF (@ListItemOnAmazon = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ListItemOnAmazon = 1'
    END
    /*
    IF (@ListItemOnEbay = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ListItemOnEbay = 1'
    END
    */

    IF (@SearchCode > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.RProductId = "' + @SearchCode + '"'
    END

    --sorting
    SET @sql_orderby = ''   
    IF @OrderBy = 5 /* Name: A to Z */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Name] ASC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 6 /* Name: Z to A */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Name] DESC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 10 /* Price: Low to High */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Price] ASC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 11 /* Price: High to Low */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Price] DESC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 15 /* creation date */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC'
    ELSE /* default sorting, 0 (position) */
    BEGIN
        --category position (display order)
        IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0 SET @sql_orderby = ' pcm.DisplayOrder ASC'

        --manufacturer position (display order)
        IF @ManufacturerId > 0
        BEGIN
            IF LEN(@sql_orderby) > 0 SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ', '
            SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ' pmm.DisplayOrder ASC'
        END

        --name
        IF LEN(@sql_orderby) > 0 SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ', '
        SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ' p.[Name] ASC'
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + '
    ORDER BY' + @sql_orderby

    --PRINT (@sql)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    DROP TABLE #FilteredCategoryIds
    DROP TABLE #FilteredSpecs
    DROP TABLE #FilteredCustomerRoleIds
    DROP TABLE #KeywordProducts

    CREATE TABLE #PageIndex 
    (
        [IndexId] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #PageIndex ([ProductId])
    SELECT ProductId
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp
    GROUP BY ProductId
    ORDER BY min([Id])

    --total records
    SET @TotalRecords = @@rowcount

    DROP TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp

    --prepare filterable specification attribute option identifier (if requested)
    IF @LoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds = 1
    BEGIN       
        CREATE TABLE #FilterableSpecs 
        (
            [SpecificationAttributeOptionId] int NOT NULL
        )
        INSERT INTO #FilterableSpecs ([SpecificationAttributeOptionId])
        SELECT DISTINCT [psam].SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        FROM [Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping] [psam] with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE [psam].[AllowFiltering] = 1
        AND [psam].[ProductId] IN (SELECT [pi].ProductId FROM #PageIndex [pi])

        --build comma separated list of filterable identifiers
        SELECT @FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds = COALESCE(@FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds + ',' , '') + CAST(SpecificationAttributeOptionId as nvarchar(4000))
        FROM #FilterableSpecs

        DROP TABLE #FilterableSpecs
    END

    --return products
    SELECT TOP (@RowsToReturn)
        p.*
    FROM
        #PageIndex [pi]
        INNER JOIN Product p with (NOLOCK) on p.Id = [pi].[ProductId]
    WHERE
        [pi].IndexId > @PageLowerBound AND 
        [pi].IndexId < @PageUpperBound
    ORDER BY
        [pi].IndexId

    DROP TABLE #PageIndex
END
```

Comment: Which SQL are you using?

Comment: @JBrooks 2016 with compatibility for 2012

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MinMaxPrices
    AS TABLE
    (
      MinPrice Money,
      MaxPrice Money
    );
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getBasedOnPrice   
        (@MinMaxPrices dbo.MinMaxPrices READONLY)  
BEGIN

    select * 
    from product p 
    where exists 
    (select 1
    from @MinMaxPrices mm
    where p.price between mm.MinPrice and mm.MaxPrice)

END

GO
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I updated my question with the full procedure. How do I slot this into what I have